# Cannot recognize/format usb flash

Tags: partitioning, usb, ntfs, format

I had a Flash stick with Ubuntu to run as live USB. I didn't need it anymore so I used the Disks utility and I formatted it. Disks sees it now as unallocated space. I want to format it to NTFS but I cannot do it with disks. Gparted has no option for the device, no mount, no unmount, no format.. nothing.

The Flash doesn't appear in Gnome.

Finally, this is the result of running `lsusb` and `fdisk -l`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13fe:3e00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 050d:945a Belkin Components F7D1101 Basic Wireless USB Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8188SU]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0039 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Optical
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2c74badc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63     4176899     2088418+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         4176900  1953520064   974671582+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16013852672 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15272 cylinders, total 31277056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000540f8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Any ideas to format it to NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

i´ve found a instruction. may it can help you:
http://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-USB-Flash-Drive-in-Ubuntu

greets
stefan

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.